# On some devices ftp connection is closed without indication

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I've made small android app, my first one. One of its function is to upload text reports to ftp server. I am using apache-commons-net. On some devices ftp server closes connection without indication. Server logs are empty.
Below there is the code of inner class performing file transfer. There are four files to be send, hence the loop. textViewResult control is used to inform user on transfer status.
 1. Do you see perhaps some obvious issues with code that might result in closed connection?
 2. "connection closed without indication" error does not really tell me anything about real source of the problem. Is there a way to get more detailed error?

edit: Problem has been reported on LG G5, H831, android 7.0. On LG H635 Android 6.0 works without issues.

edit2: Stacktrace

```
Data uploading error:
Connection closed without indication.

 Connection info: 
MOBILE
UMTS
CONNECTED

 Stack Trace:
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:324)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:300)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.connectAction(FTP.java:438)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.connectAction(FTPClient.java:962)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.connectAction(FTPClient.java:950)
org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:244)
org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
com.jimmorr.t9a.t9amagicflux.ReportBattleResults$ConnectFTP.doInBackground(ReportBattleResults.java:555)
com.jimmorr.t9a.t9amagicflux.ReportBattleResults$ConnectFTP.doInBackground(ReportBattleResults.java:510)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)


private class ConnectFTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String resp;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        protected Long doInBackground(String message) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
                android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
            String server = "ftp....";
            int port = 21;
            String user = "user...";
            String pass = "pass...";

            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {

                ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("public_ftp/incoming");

                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


                for (int j = 0; j<2;j++) {

                    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k = k + 2) {

                        OutputStream outputStream1;
                        Log.v(strings[k + 1]+" pass:"+j+" folder change:"+success, strings[k]);
                        outputStream1 = ftpClient.storeFileStream(strings[k + 1]);
                        outputStream1.write(strings[k].getBytes());
                        outputStream1.close();
                        if (j==0) resp = "main files sending :"+ k+"/4";
                        else resp = "backup files sending :"+ k+"/4";


                        if (!ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
                            ftpClient.logout();
                            ftpClient.disconnect();
                            System.err.println("File transfer failed.");
                            throw new IOException();
                            //System.exit(1);

                        }

                    }

                    success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_ftp/back_up");
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                }
                return resp;



            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                String str = "Data uploading error:\n" + ex.getMessage();
                textViewResult.setText(str);



            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                        ftpClient.logout();
                        ftpClient.disconnect();

                    }
                    return null;
                } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("FTP connection",ex.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }




            //return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ReportBattleResults.this,
                    "Sending Battle Report",
                    "sending data");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please let us in which device you are facing this issue, For Instance: The device model, device OS version and so on

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j<2;j++) {

                    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k = k + 2)`. Pretty unreadable code. Why this mess?

Comment: `textViewResult.setText(str);`. You cannot set the text for a TextView in doInBackground(). It will make your app crash. Do it in onPostExecute().

Comment: The big loop is for uploading copy of the files to ("/public_ftp/back_up");

The textViewResult.setText(str); in catch works with no issues. Dunno why ;)

Comment: Collecting data on the devices will take me a while - it happens on users installations. All devices I have access to work properly so no way to usb-debug it.

Comment: Problem noticed on LG G5, H831, android 7.0

Comment: On LG H635 Android 6.0 works properly.

Comment: @greenapps: you are correct. App was crashing on setting the textView but it worked nevertheless. Corrected it. Added stack trace and waiting for users to report the error with stack trace.